# What stack is appropriate for discussing the art of writing journals?

Tags: support, scope

I had a specific question: Should the authors refer to themselves as

> We would like to thank the technical contribution of Dr. Sam Adams...

or

> The authors would like to thank Dr. Sam Adams

?

I was wondering if tex.stackexchange.com is the right place to discuss the above question or if there's a separate stack on the art of writing (encompassing everything - technical, journalistic, text, fantasy, fiction, etc. - i.e. all types of writing).

Comment: No, it's not on-topic on TeX.SE. Anyway: I have seen and used the "The authors [of this paper] .." form.

Comment: +1 for asking on meta before just posting the question! Very considerate of you!

Comment: You can also ask in the chat room if you are unsure if a question is on-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The nearest match to a *site* dedicated to evaluating a particular text is [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) - be sure to read their [FAQ](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq).

You might also find some assistance on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I agree, and would actually prefer Academia in this case because it's an academic publication. TeX.SE is not the right place to ask about this.